# PulseAudio error in build methode with conan

Tags: sdl-2, conan, conan-2

I have `conan 2.0.9`
here is all the other information

```
    Profile build:
[settings]
arch=x86_64
build_type=Release
compiler=gcc
compiler.cppstd=gnu17
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
compiler.version=11
os=Linux
[conf]
tools.system.package_manager:mode=install
tools.system.package_manager:sudo=True
```

and I try to install **SDL2**. So my Conanfile.txt is simply

```
[requires]
sdl/2.26.5

[generators]
CMakeDeps
CMakeToolchain
```

I do the classic `conan install . --output-folder=build --build=missing` .

Everything is fine until, conan try to install a needed library **Pulseaudio** and here it stop with this error

```
  CCLD     librtp.la
/usr/bin/ld: /home/etienne/.conan2/p/mpg120f2357dca7957/p/lib/libmpg123.a(libmpg123_la-libmpg123.o): in function `mpg123_eq_change':
libmpg123.c:(.text+0xe6d): undefined reference to `__exp_finite'
/usr/bin/ld: libmpg123.c:(.text+0x1045): undefined reference to `__exp_finite'
/usr/bin/ld: libmpg123.c:(.text+0x1220): undefined reference to `__exp_finite'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/etienne/.conan2/p/mpg120f2357dca7957/p/lib/libmpg123.a(libmpg123_la-frame.o): in function `INT123_do_rva':
frame.c:(.text+0x18ee): undefined reference to `__exp_finite'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/etienne/.conan2/p/mpg120f2357dca7957/p/lib/libmpg123.a(libmpg123_la-frame.o): in function `mpg123_volume_change_db':
frame.c:(.text+0x1a8a): undefined reference to `__exp_finite'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/etienne/.conan2/p/mpg120f2357dca7957/p/lib/libmpg123.a(libmpg123_la-tabinit.o): in function `INT123_make_conv16to8_table':
tabinit.c:(.text+0xfab): undefined reference to `__log_finite'
/usr/bin/ld: tabinit.c:(.text+0x1009): undefined reference to `__log_finite'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/etienne/.conan2/p/mpg120f2357dca7957/p/lib/libmpg123.a(libmpg123_la-layer3.o): in function `INT123_init_layer3_gainpow2_mmx':
layer3.c:(.text+0x3fdb): undefined reference to `__exp2_finite'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/etienne/.conan2/p/mpg120f2357dca7957/p/lib/libmpg123.a(libmpg123_la-layer3.o): in function `INT123_init_layer3_gainpow2':
layer3.c:(.text+0x402b): undefined reference to `__exp2_finite'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/etienne/.conan2/p/mpg120f2357dca7957/p/lib/libmpg123.a(libmpg123_la-libmpg123.o): in function `mpg123_eq_change':
libmpg123.c:(.text+0xe6d): undefined reference to `__exp_finite'
/usr/bin/ld: libmpg123.c:(.text+0x1045): undefined reference to `__exp_finite'
/usr/bin/ld: libmpg123.c:(.text+0x1220): undefined reference to `__exp_finite'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/etienne/.conan2/p/mpg120f2357dca7957/p/lib/libmpg123.a(libmpg123_la-frame.o): in function `INT123_do_rva':
frame.c:(.text+0x18ee): undefined reference to `__exp_finite'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/etienne/.conan2/p/mpg120f2357dca7957/p/lib/libmpg123.a(libmpg123_la-frame.o): in function `mpg123_volume_change_db':
frame.c:(.text+0x1a8a): undefined reference to `__exp_finite'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/etienne/.conan2/p/mpg120f2357dca7957/p/lib/libmpg123.a(libmpg123_la-tabinit.o): in function `INT123_make_conv16to8_table':
tabinit.c:(.text+0xfab): undefined reference to `__log_finite'
/usr/bin/ld: tabinit.c:(.text+0x1009): undefined reference to `__log_finite'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/etienne/.conan2/p/mpg120f2357dca7957/p/lib/libmpg123.a(libmpg123_la-layer3.o): in function `INT123_init_layer3_gainpow2_mmx':
layer3.c:(.text+0x3fdb): undefined reference to `__exp2_finite'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/etienne/.conan2/p/mpg120f2357dca7957/p/lib/libmpg123.a(libmpg123_la-layer3.o): in function `INT123_init_layer3_gainpow2':
layer3.c:(.text+0x402b): undefined reference to `__exp2_finite'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [Makefile:7149 : pacat] Erreur 1
make[3]: *** Attente des tâches non terminées....
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [Makefile:7167 : pactl] Erreur 1
ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')
ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')
ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')
ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')
ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')
ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')
make[3] : on quitte le répertoire « /home/etienne/.conan2/p/b/pulsec07d56d7019eb/b/build-release/src »
make[2]: *** [Makefile:5348 : all] Erreur 2
make[2] : on quitte le répertoire « /home/etienne/.conan2/p/b/pulsec07d56d7019eb/b/build-release/src »
make[1]: *** [Makefile:828 : all-recursive] Erreur 1
make[1] : on quitte le répertoire « /home/etienne/.conan2/p/b/pulsec07d56d7019eb/b/build-release »
make: *** [Makefile:643 : all] Erreur 2

pulseaudio/13.0: ERROR: 
Package '8cbe13a46946620a9a894d9f1850dca80d619f0b' build failed
pulseaudio/13.0: WARN: Build folder /home/etienne/.conan2/p/b/pulsec07d56d7019eb/b/build-release
*********************************************************
Recipe 'pulseaudio/13.0' cannot build its binary
It is possible that this recipe is not Conan 2.0 ready
If the recipe comes from ConanCenter check: https://conan.io/cci-v2.html
If it is your recipe, check if it is updated to 2.0
*********************************************************

ERROR: pulseaudio/13.0: Error in build() method, line 128
    autotools.make()
    ConanException: Error 2 while executing
```

This is the just end of the logs but here is the [full log](https://pastebin.com/jFJHEKHL), yet the error seems to be at the end.

Thank you in advance for your help,

I try to install just Audiopulse with the three different versions proposed on [conan server](https://conan.io/center/pulseaudio?os=Linux&tab=dependencies) but with the same effect.

Comment: Conan  3.10.06 doesn't exist, could you please double check it?

Comment: If the ``audiopulse`` library is failing, it would be good to report and reproduce it with something like ``conan install --requires=audiopulse/version --build=missing``, and also report your platform (os, compiler, compiler version, etc), and provide the full log, as it will contain information about dependencies versions, etc.

Comment: Thank for your answer. For your first remark indeed it is 3.10.6. I add information with my platform and the full log. Also `conan install --requires=audiopulse/version --build=missing` end with `ERROR: Missing prebuilt package for 'pulseaudio/14.2'`

Comment: Conan 3.10.6 version does NOT exist. It is impossible that you are using it.

Comment: I suggest filing a ticket in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues, this format is not great for support. You would need the exact command ``--requires=audiopulse/version`` does not exist, and ``--build=missing`` is incompatible with ``Missing prebuilt package``, so something weird is going on there. Please try to provide full, clear details to reproduce in the ticket.

Comment: Indeed I get confuse with my version of Python

Comment: Also I make a mistake with the name of the library it is Pulseaudio and no Audiopulse, sorry for these typos.

Comment: So `--requires=pulseaudio/14.2` should exists.

Comment: I am not sure to get your last point with `--build=missing`.

Comment: In theory it is impossible to get a missing binary if you type ``--build=missing``, so there is something that doesn't completely make sense, this is why a ticket in Github makes sense.